# Is the following grammar correct?

Tags: java, algorithm, grammar

I'm trying to check for correctness of grammar using recursive descent parsing for the following grammar:

```
<FACTOR> ::= <EXPR> | i
<TERM> ::= <FACTOR> * <TERM> | <FACTOR>
<EXPR> ::= <TERM> + <EXPR> | <TERM>
```

The problem, is that it seems the grammar is recursive since `factor` can be `expr` which can be `term` which can be `factor`. So it seems impossible to check this for correctness using a program. However I'm not sure this is correct since this was given as an assignment. Can someone tell me if it's correct, and if true, a possible algorithm I can use to check this?

Thanks.

Don't know if it might help, but here's my current code:

```
//Variable to store our current character index
static int i = 0;
//Variable to store our input string
static String input;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter text to check for correctness: ");
    input = scan.nextLine();
    if(input.charAt(input.length() - 1) != '#'){
        input += scan.nextLine();                    
    }
    //Remove all spaces just to prevent space interference
    input = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
    if(Factor(nextChar()))
    {
        System.out.println("Your text input is correct");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Your text input does not conform with the grammar");
    }
}

public static boolean Factor(char ourChar){
    //<factor> ::= <expr> | i        
    if(ourChar == '#')
    {
        //If it's # we should bounce back if and return true since no errors yet
        return true;
    }
    if(ourChar == 'i')
    {
        //if it's i then return true
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //so the character is not i, let's check if satisfies the Expr grammar
        if(!Expr(ourChar))
        {
            //oooh, it's not return false!
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }        
}

public static boolean Expr(char ourChar){
    //<expr> ::= <term> + <expr> | <term>
    //Before you can be an expression, you must start with a term
    if(!Term(ourChar))
        //so it doesn't start with term? Bounce back dear
        return false;
    if(nextChar() != '+'){
        //The next character is not a plus, return false to sender
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //So it's plus? Ok, let's check if the next character is another expr
        if(!Expr(nextChar()))
            return false;
        else
            //Everybody satisfied, return true
            return true;
    }
}

public static boolean Term(char ourChar){
    //<term> ::= <factor> * <term> | <factor>
    //If the character does not start with a factor bounce back
    if(!Factor(ourChar))
        return false;
    if(nextChar() != '*'){
        //Yekpa! The factor is not followed by * so bounce back
        return false;
    }
    else{
        //SO, it's a star. Ok, if it's followed by a term, bounce back
        if(!Term(nextChar()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        //Well, all bouncers satisfied, so return true
        return true;
    }
}

public static char nextChar(){
    i++;
    return input.charAt(i - 1);
}
```

Comment: If it's recursive decent, then the recursion should be the algorithm.  It will stop when <FACTOR> is not an <EXPR>, in which it will expand to i and stop recursing.  You basically need just one thing in your grammer to eventually end in a non-recursive call for it to work right.

Comment: I don't understand. In my algorithm, it stops when expr is supplied, since expr will check if it's a term, which will again check if it's a factor which will check again if it's an expression and so on...

Comment: Thats not how a RD parser works.  You have a method that represents each grammar rule, and in there you have logic that determines if it needs to continue to the next grammar rule or stop.  So, for <FACTOR> it would be something like "if we have 'i', return, else <EXPR>", and <EXPR> you would have "if there is no '*', <FACTOR>, else <FACTOR> * <TERM>'.  In your grammar above, <FACTOR> is the stopping point, as it evaluates to 'i' eventually.

Comment: @CodeChimp: So you're saying the grammar is not correct? For instance, would the grammar work for `i * i`?

Comment: Just added the code I'm using. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the first rule should be: `<FACTOR> ::= ( <EXPR> ) | i`, which is more standard. Otherwise, (1) you cannot use parentheses in your expressions, and (2) the grammar is ambiguous.

Comment: Aha, I was hoping to hear that. SO the grammar is wrong... right?

Comment: I think the grammar is fine.  It has some way to terminate, and I don't see any place where there is an infinite loop or anything.  Looking at your code, however, I don't think you implemented what I would consider a "recursive decent parser".  For instance, I would expect the input to the Function, Expr, and Term to be a String, since Term and Expr can be things like "XXX + XXX".

Comment: @rtuner: Ok, submitted as answer.

Comment: Thanks, just saw it. I've been on that, but the problem is when I supply (i + (i * i)), since <factor> calls <expr> which calls <term> which calls <factor> again, it fails. @CodeChimp, I've also been thinking about the string input, but I don't think it's supposed to accept 'XXX + XXX'.

Comment: @rtuner: factor shouldn't call expr until after it sees a (. So with `(i + (i * i))`, factor will first be called with input `(`, resulting in a recursive call, and then with input `i`, which should immediately resolve without another recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar as typed in the question does not correspond with normal expression syntax, since it doesn't allow parentheses. It's also ambiguous. So I'll go with *"No, the following grammar is not correct."*

I'd suggest the following grammar (note the parentheses):

```
<FACTOR> ::= ( <EXPR> ) | i
<TERM> ::= <FACTOR> * <TERM> | <FACTOR>
<EXPR> ::= <TERM> + <EXPR> | <TERM>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The Start Symbol seams to be "<"EXPR">" and not "<"FACTOR">". You should check this.
2. The grammar is ambiguous. For example "i" can be derivated by 
      "<"FACTOR">" => i
         or 
      "<"FACTOR">" => "<"EXPR">" => "<"TERM">" => "<"FACTOR">" => i
3. "<"FACTOR> is equivalent to "<"EXPR">" and to "<"TERM">", 
    because
      "<"FACTOR">" ::= "<"EXPR">" and 
      "<"TERM">" ::= "<"FACTOR">" and
      "<"EXPR">" ::= "<"TERM">"
   so, u can put
   "<"EXPR">" ::= i + "<"EXPR">" | i * "<"EXPR">" | i
   this CFG has no ambiguity, no left-recursion, but it should be right-factorized, so you can use:
   "<"EXPR">" ::= i "<"AUX">"
   "<"AUX">" ::= + "<"EXPR">" | * "<"EXPR">" | e
   (e is the Empty String)

You can build the recursive descent parsing for this grammar, since this grammar is LL(1) and produce the same language.

Good luck.

Comment: The grammar you propose, uses a different style, which (among other things) does not encode the priorities of operators — hence, it will be good for a recogniser/validator, but very bad for a parser that needs to construct an AST.

Comment: Priorities depend on the language your are defining. Some language use only asociativity and dont use priorities. If I would have the requirements, I would proppose the rigth grammar.